# How to make iOS simulator always stay on top in macOS

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, visual-studio-code, simulator

I'm using **macOS Catalina** and **VS Code 1.41.1**, how to make the iOS simulator always stay on top of other windows?

Answer (score 55):

[image]

If you're using Xcode `v12.0.0` or higher, you can use `Stay On Top` option from `Window` tab.

Answer (score 1):

A plugin exists for this.

Start by installing mySIMBL: https://github.com/w0lfschild/mySIMBL

Next, download this entire repo: https://github.com/rwu823/afloat

Extract the zip file and open the folder in Finder. Navigate to the “bundle” folder. You should see two files: “Afloat.bundle” and “SIMBL-0.9.9.pkg.”

With the mySIMBL application still running, drag and drop the “Afloat.bundle” file to the mySIMBL app window. Ensure that Afloat appears in the mySIMBL Plugins window and that there is a green dot next to it.

Restart your Mac. Afloat should be working now.

To make your app window “Always on Top,” click on the “Window” option in the menu and select “Keep Afloat.”